# bitwise AND in java with operator "&"

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I just read this code following:

```
byte[] bts = {8, 0, 0, 0};
if ((bts[i] & 0x01) == 0x01)
```

Does this do the same thing as

```
if (bts[i] == 0x01)
```

If not,what's the difference between them?

And what is the first way trying to do here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

```
if(bts[i] == 0x01)
```

means if bts[i] is equal to 1.

```
if((bts[i] & 0x01) == 0x01)
```

means if the least significant bit of bts[i] is equal to 1.

Example.

```
bts[i] = 9 //1001 in binary

if(bts[i] == 0x01) //false

if((bts[i] & 0x01) == 0x01) //true
```

Comment: @Johnny: E.g., **all odd numbers** match the `& 0x01` test, but only `0x01` matches the `== 0x01` test.

Comment: It seems that all odd numbers will return true here.

Comment: @JohnnyChen: Do I hear an echo? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

(`0x1001 & 0x01) == 0x01`, but

```
0x1001 != 0x01
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't, the first will check only the last bit - if it's `1`, it will return true regardless of the others.

The second one will return true if only the last bit is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same thing. `0x01` is just `1`. Now,

```
if (bts[i] == 0x01)
```

checks if `bts[i]` is equal to `1`.

```
if ((bts[i] & 0x01) == 0x01)
```

Checks if the last (least significant) bit of `bts[i]` is equal to `1`. In the binary system, all odd numbers have the last bit equal to `1`. So, `if ((bts[i] & 0x01) == 0x01)` is basically checking, if the number in `bts[i]` is odd. It could be written as `if (bts[i] % 2 == 1)`, too.